# Cookies appearing briefly and disappearing on redirect

Tags: authentication, http, redirect, cookies, fetch-api

I'm working on a deployed React app that talks to an Express server. On the client side I have a /account/login page that sends a request to /login. The main login logic on the server side looks like this:

```js
res
.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin)
.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
.cookie('JWTAuthToken', token, { httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: 'none', path: "/" })
.cookie('LoggedIn', true, { httpOnly: false, secure: true, sameSite: 'none', path: "/" })
.send({ /* send back some user display data (eg username, etc.) */ });
```

On the client side, I make the request using `fetch` like this:

```js
fetch(/* /api/login... */, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
  body: JSON.stringify({email, password}),
  credentials: 'include'
})
.then(res => return res.json())
.then(data => {
  // reading some data from response and setting to localStorage, etc.
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.location.href = '/account';
  }, 1000);
})
```

Opening devtools on both Edge and Chrome, I see that when I click the Login button, and the request goes through, the `JWTAuthToken` and `LoggedIn` cookies **briefly appear in my application window, but disappear immediately after the page redirects** to `/account` (I even added a 1 second delay to the redirect for debugging, but they still disappear once the URL changes).

I'm not sure why these cookies aren't persisting though. Every other cookie (e.g. those from Stripe, etc.) are.
Also, the domain of these cookies is different from all others. My `JWTAuthToken` and `LoggedIn` cookies originate from my server URL, whereas all the other cookies originate from `.<client domain name>.org`. This doesn't seem like it would cause a problem, but I might be wrong.

(Everything looks good from the server side, there aren't any errors)

Could this be a CORS issue? I'm using Azure App Service to host both client and server, if that's relevant info.